# Hiding NSMenu while the dock remains active

Tags: cocoa, menu, hide, visible, dock

I want my app to show his menu on launch only if the user didn't open a file. Now I can't seem to make it work. Hiding the menu makes the dock and the status bar invisible. I want them to still be there, but not with my own menu (e.g. if you open a file from finder, the finder menu is still visible, but my app opens a window that handles the file, and quits if the user cancels or on completion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably didn't explain it well enough, but here's what I did to solve it :

- Add this line to the plist of my app (this produces an app without dock icon or menu), the dock and the menu bar will still be there, but won't be changed by the app :

  LSUIElement

(And set the checkbox to *true*).

This makes your app UI-only (it doesn't show his NSMenu nor does it add an icon to the dock, but just shows your GUI.